# How a C program has more than one tanslation units?

Tags: c

From C11 standard:

> A source file together with all the headers and source files included
>   via the preprocessing directive #include is known as a preprocessing
>   translation unit. After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation
>   unit is called a translation unit

and

> The separate translation units of a program communicate by (for
>   example) calls to functions whose identifiers have external linkage,
>   manipulation of objects whose identifiers have external linkage, or
>   manipulation of data files. Translation units may be separately
>   translated and then later linked to produce an executable program.

It seems a C program starts with a so called "main.c" and include other libraries and files, so it is still one translation unit even multiple files are included. In what situation, a C program has multiple translation units?

Can you give me an example?

I'm new to C and thanks for your advices!

Comment: Because if you only had one translation unit you would have only one file to put _all_ your code and that's just silly.

Comment: Consider a ".c" file that has only one function.  It would be a *translation unit*.  A good idea is not put everything into the `main.c` file.

Comment: Since you're new to C, I'll let you know that C and C++ are different languages.  So get rid of the `C++` tag.

Comment: One advantage to multiple files is that when a file compiles with zero errors and zero warnings, it doesn't have to be compiled again (*unless one of its header file or dependencies changes*).  Not having to compile files speeds up the build process (linking object files is faster than translating source files into object files).

Comment: An `#include`d file is not a library or object file. There is a reason you have to link a program after compilation (i.e. translation).

Comment: Object libraries are the result of translation units.  You link multiple object files to produce a single executable.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious not necessarily, you could still organize your code into files, but have `main.c` do `#include` to get all the other files. (Not a good idea, but possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems a C program starts with a so called "main.c" and include other libraries and files, so it is still one translation unit even multiple files are included. In what situation, a C program has multiple translation units?

Sure, it starts that way.

But as your project grows, you may well add files that cannot/should not be `#include`d, such as a `some-implementations.c`. If you dumped all your definitions in `main.c` you'd have a bad time.

Furthermore, every non-header-only library you link in adds one or more additional translation units.

I'm not going to give a specific example, but you can look at practically *any* C project on GitHub, Sourceforge, Google Code etc to see it for yourself.

Comment: inb4 yes I know Google Code is only an archive now

Comment: "every non-header-only library you link in adds one or more additional translation units." Got you, thanks!